# Something went wrong while installing sample data. Please check var/log/system.log for details during Magento installation

Tags: php, magento

I am a beginner in **Magento**. When i was trying to install **"Magento-CE-2.0.0+Samples-2015-11-17-06-11-18.zip"** on my local server using **Wamp**,it first gets stuck at 90%, after quite a while, it shows *"Success"* but at the end of the page it shows the following error-

> "Something went wrong while installing sample data. Please check
>   var/log/system.log for details. You can retry installing the data now
>   or just start using Magento"

I checked the **"var/log/system.log"** and there is this message-

> [2015-12-21 09:42:48] main.ERROR: Sample Data error: Warning:
>   IntlDateFormatter::parse(): Date parsing failed in
>   C:\wamp\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone.php
>   on line 166 [] []

when i click at the button *"Launch Magento Admin"* which is situated at the bottom of the page, i get this error

[image]

> What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: `You can retry installing the data`- seems the log speaks for itself?

Comment: It exactly says that with a warning sign at the bottom of the page @Naruto